# Допустимо ли говорить "иной, чем"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Сегодня образовательная система иная, чем в советское время". Не уверена, что это предложение удачно составлено. Можно ли сказать "иной, чем что-либо"?

Answer (score 2):

**Выражение "иная, чем"  применяется совершенно свободно, причем в разных тестах любого стиля** (делового, научного, художественного), например:

Поэтому организация памяти у него **иная, чем** на обычных ПК или ноутбуках. [Д. Усенков. Электронный помощник в кармане // «Наука и жизнь», 2006]

...эта весна, весна его первой любви, тоже была **совершенно иная, чем** все прежние весны. [И. А. Бунин. Митина любовь (1924)]

**И всё-таки предложение не кажется удачным, но что такое с ним?** В качестве версии могу предложить **разговорный (упрощённый) синтаксис**, не соответствующий стилистке подобных статей.

**К вопросу о частотности применения выражений в Нацкорпусе**: "иной, чем" ― 170 примеров, "иная, чем" ― 107 примеров. Поэтому сомневаться в нормативности данных конструкций как-то не приходится:  они использовались и используются в художественных произведениях, в научной и технической литературе ― иными словами, везде.

Answer (score 1):

> Допустимо ли говорить *“иной, чем”*?

В принципе, так говорят.

См. примеры:

*Наличие побочного акцента означает, что в одной и той же словоформе имеются два и более центра выделения, т. е. здесь ситуация **иная, чем** в рассмотренных ранее случаях, где выделялся только один слог.*

*Семантика диалектного слова **иная, чем** была в русской письменности.*

И всё  же Ваше предложение я бы постарался как-то перестроить.

Как вариант:

***Сегодня образовательная система строится*** (несколько/совершенно...) **иначе, чем в советское время.**

Answer (score 0):

Если к тексту не предъявляется повышенных требований, то можно оставить.
Но вообще-то правильным вариантом будет "отличный от".

Современная система отлична от той, что была...

Или "иная в сравнении с" / "по сравнению с" (это уже похуже).

Конструкции с "чем" строго нормативно используются только со сравнительной степенью прилагательный и наречий, а иной/другой таковыми не являются.